# R: rgdal writing GeoJSON

Tags: r, geojson, gdal, rgdal, ropensci

I'm having a problem with rgdal which drops the projection information when writing geoJSON files.

```
library(rgdal)

inputJSON<- readOGR("test.geojson", "OGRGeoJSON") # works!
```

If i type `summary(inputJSON)` i get the following output:

```
Object of class SpatialPointsDataFrame

Coordinates:
          min      max
coords.x1   0 499690.8
coords.x2   0 321771.2
Is projected: TRUE 
proj4string :
[+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=13.33333333333333 +k=1 +x_0=450000 +y_0=-5000000
+ellps=bessel +towgs84=577.326,90.129,463.919,5.137,1.474,5.297,2.4232 +units=m +no_defs]
```

Thats telling me that the file was successfully read into R and that it also gets the projection information.

After some data manipulating I then want to save my data.frame (inputJSON) as a new geoJSON file using the following command:

```
writeOGR(inputJSON, "outTest.geojson", layer="inputJSON", driver="GeoJSON",check_exists = FALSE)
```

that also produces the desired geoJSON file but it does not write the projection information into it and well a geoJSON file without that information is pretty much (for my proposes) useless.

For comparison the beginning of the input file (test.geojson):

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31258" } },

"features": [
```

The file produced (outTest.geojson):

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",

"features": [
```

so this:

```
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31258" } },
```

important part is missing.

If I`m not mistaken my rgdal version is

> rgdal’ version 1.0-6

and should be the newest. Well I also tried other packages with a available geoJSON file writer (`geojsonio,leafletR`) but non of them considers the projection. 
So what Im I missing? Is there any possibility to make that work? 
Im thinking that the GeoJSON driver of ogr2ogr (which the package is based on) does not handle the projection at all. Transferring a shapefile to a geoJSON file over the commandline the resulting geoJSON file also misses the projection information. Im really confused!

So what im i missing?

Does anyone have (any) solution?

Comment: take a look [here](https://github.com/Robinlovelace/Creating-maps-in-R/blob/master/vignettes/geoJSON.Rmd). Robin shows how to deal with this GDAL inadequacy.

Comment: Thank you! I found that page,too. The solution to write the missing line manually works for the case if i have a geoJSON file as input file so i can easily "copy paste" the missing line. But when the input file for example is a shapefile, that solution is pretty messy having in the best of cases to look up the EPSG code (not possible with R?) and then manually write that information into the geoJOSN file.
Its really strange for example if I download a WFS layer and save it as geoJSON using the command line the projection information is written into the file. So generally it should be possible?

Comment: Note that in RFC 7946 (the newest format proposal), only WS84 is used, citing interoperability issues. You could jump the gun and use that mode instead, with `RFC7946=YES` in the creation options.

Comment: To add, [paragraph 4 of the RFC 7946 specification](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946) states: "the use of alternative coordinate reference systems was
   specified in [GJ2008], but it has been removed from this version of
   the specification ... In general, GeoJSON
   processing software is not expected to have access to coordinate
   reference system databases or to have network access to coordinate
   reference system transformation parameters."